Does an expanding de-Sitter bubble create mass from nothing?
Dear Physics Stack Exchange Community,
I am experimenting a bit with different kinds of FLRW solutions to the Einstein equations, in particular with the de-Sitter solution, which comes from choosing $p=-e$ as equation of state. In the comoving frame of the expanding/collapsing fluid, the line element and Friedmann equations write out as
$$
\begin{align}
 \mathrm{d}s^2= -\mathrm{d}\tau^2&+a(\tau)^2\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}r^2}{1-kr^2}+r^2\mathrm{d}\Omega^2\right)\, , \\
 \textbf{I.}&\quad\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\right)^2=\frac{8\pi}{3}e-\frac{k}{a^2}\,,\nonumber\\
 \textbf{II.}&\,\,\,\,\quad\frac{\ddot{a}}{a}=-\frac{4\pi}{3}(e+3p)\,,\nonumber\\
 \textbf{III.}&\quad\Rightarrow\dot{e}=-3\,\frac{\dot{a}}{a}(e+p)\,,\nonumber
\end{align}
$$
where $\textbf{I}$ and $\textbf{II}$ combined yield $\textbf{III}$, ignoring the cosmological constant $\Lambda$. Now, plugging in the de-Sitter equation of state $p=-e$ into $\textbf{III}$, one gets $e=\rm{const.}\equiv e_0$, meaning the energy density stays constant regardless of how much the de-Sitter bubble has expanded. Next, we solve $\textbf{I}$:
$$
\dot{a}^2=\frac{8\pi}{3}e_0 a^2-k\, ,
$$
which can be solved with the use of the hyperbolic functions
$$
a(\tau) = \rm{cosh}\left(\sqrt{ \textit{k} } \tau\right)\, ,
$$
corresponding to the initial conditions $a_0 = 1$, $ \dot{a}_0 = 0 $ and $ k=\frac{8\pi}{3}e_0 $, representing an expanding de-Sitter bubble.
The question
If we start with a finite size de-Sitter bubble with a radius of $r_0$, it will keep expanding according to $r_{\rm{Bubble}}=a(\tau)r_0$ with an energy density $e_0$ everywhere inside the bubble. Since the bubble is growing, the region with the energy density of $e_0$ is growing too. If we assume that everywhere outside the bubble is vacuum with $e=0$, it seems to me that the de-Sitter bubble is creating mass from nothing. Is this true? If yes, what is the intuitive explanation behind this mass generation?

You've just rediscovered the implication of the stress-energy tensor associated with the cosmological constant.

Daniel asked: »it seems to me that the de-Sitter bubble is creating mass from nothing. Is this true?« - seems like it, since Wikipedia wrote: »If considered as a "source term" in the field equation, it can be viewed as equivalent to the mass of empty space«
